# Cookie being set by an image?

Tags: http, cookies

I am trying to work out how cookies are being set on a website, I have scoured the page source and can see how most of them are being generated.

However, there is one cookie that appears on page load that I can't track down.

Is it possible that a cookie is being set when an image is being requested from a remote server? If so, can I inspect that http request response with a tool to find out if it contains the cookie?

Comment: Your browser should have a network tab in bis developer tools, there you can see the Cookie header. Try to press F12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A request for an image is basically the same as a request for a html page. It uses the same request/response structure. So yes you can set a cookie on an image request.

The request/response can be seen in most modern browsers. In FireFox there is under tools -> Web Developer -> Network a tool that shows the requests/responses from all calls being made on a page. Opera and Chrome have similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now. Have been able to inspect the request in FireFox developer tools

Answer (score 8):

Any HTTP-Request can set a cookie, if the server says so.

> Cookies are set using the Set-Cookie HTTP header, sent in an HTTP response from the web server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie